# Need Alternate Approach Instead of `arguments.callee` in jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

With `arguments.callee deprecated I would like to find al alternative approach to extend a jQuery plugin I created to execute one of its built in methods from the outside.

My sample jQuery plugin:

```
(function($) {
$.myPlugin = function(options) {
  // normal var and methods

  // this is to execute a method from outside
  arguments.callee.close = function() {
    // to do when this is called
  }
}
}(jQuery))
```

The plugin would be used for it’s normal use with this

```
$(selector).myPlugin();
```

And this is to trigger the “close” method inside the plugin

```
$(selector).myPlugin.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this and have this to share:

```
(function($) {
  function myPlugin(options) {
    // normal var and methods: do whatever I want...

    myPlugin.close = myPlugin.close.bind(this);
  }

  myPlugin.close = function() {
    // do this thing
  }

  $.fn.myPlugin = myPlugin;

}(jQuery));
```

This allows me to call the close method with this:

```
$(selector).myPlugin.close();
```